# MessageBodyWriter vs. WriterInterceptor

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I am a bit confused about the exact intention of the `WriterInterceptor` Interface of the ***JAX-RS*** 2.0 specification.

What I know so far:

- `WriterInterceptor` is called before `MessageBodyWriter`
- Both Interfaces grant access to the same variables
- `MessageBodyWriter` is concerned with translating an `object` into a *stream*
- Arun Gupta states in his Java EE 7 book that *Writer/Reader Inteceptors* are mainly concerned with marshalling and unmarshalling of HTTP bodies.

My questionis: For which intent should the *Reader/Writer Interceptor* be used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server-side you can let the Message Body Writers do the entity marshalling and while the Interceptors can take care of:

- performing GZIP compression of the marshalled entity,
- wrapping the marshalled entity in a Digital Signature enveloppe (reader interceptor could verify a signature before further processing),
- adding Cache control headers

For example:

```
@Override
void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext ctx) ... {
    OutputStream old = ctx.getOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(old);
    ctx.setOutputStream(gzipOutputStream);
    updateHeaders(ctx);
    try {
        ctx.proceed();
    } finally {
        gzipOutputStream.finish();
        ctx.setOutputStream(old);
    }
}
```

(code above comes from the JAX-RS 2.0 spec, section 6.3)

HTH.